# MVVM Light Binding

Tags: binding, mvvm-light, inotifypropertychanged

Im working on a WPF project and use MVVM light. The textbox binding seem to not work. Do you have any idea why ? I use the INotifyPorpertyChanged implementation through the ViewModelBase Class implemented in the MVVM light framework.

I have 2 textboxes Username and Password...and i would like that properties linked to these controls have their value changed when the user enters characters in both textfields.

Thank you.

**ViewModel**

```cs
  #region Helpers Properties

        private UserBLL UserBLLManager;
        public UserBO User;
        public RelayCommand AddNewUserCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand TryToLoginCommand { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            if (UserBLLManager == null)//service
                UserBLLManager = new UserBLL();

            if (User == null)//model
                User = new UserBO();

            AddNewUserCommand = new RelayCommand(() => AddNewUser());
            TryToLoginCommand = new RelayCommand(() => TryToLogin());
        }


            public void AddNewUser()
            {
                 //do stuff

            }

        }
    }
```

**Model**

```cs
public class UserBO:ObservableObject
        {   
            private string username;
            public string Username
            {
                get { return username; }
                set
                {
                    if (value != username)
                    {
                        username = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("Username");
                    }
                }
            }

            private string password;
            public string Password
            {
                get { return password; }
                set
                {
                    if (value != password)
                    {
                        password = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("Password");
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
```

**ServiceLocator**

```cs
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {

        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);


            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();

        }

        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
            }
        }

        public static void Cleanup()
        {
            // TODO Clear the ViewModels
        }
}
```

**View**

```xml
    <Window x:Class="MyCook.MainView"
                DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

            <Grid>

                        <TextBox Name="Username_TxtBox" Text="{Binding User.Username,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>

                        <TextBox Name="Pwd_TxtBox" Text="{Binding User.Password,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></TextBox>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The user should be public. Binding to private properties makes no sense.

2) If you want the underlying properties to change once the users enters values you have to set the binding to TwoWay:

```
Text="{Binding User.Username,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

3) Entity classes should not derive from `ViewModelBase`. Instead go for `ObservableObject`.

Comment: I made the change you notified but it still not working (I edited my code). I changed the derivation in my model class (UserBO) as u said...